# Save values from Delphi to Disk: "Save" and "Save as"

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, lazarus

I am creatinga program that saves some information (usually edit fields) on the disk using the following code:

```
  procedure TForm1.ToolButton3Click(Sender: TObject);   
    begin    
    if  Savedialog1.Execute then
         begin
            AssignFile(myFile, save.filename);
            ReWrite(myFile);
            customer.Name:=name.text;
            customer.LastName:= LastName.Text;
           //[...] <-- much more fields
            Write(myFile, customer);
            CloseFile(myFile);  
            end;

end;
```

And this code to open:

```
procedure TForm1.ToolButton12Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if opendlg.execute then begin
     Form1.Caption := 'Program Name '+' - '+extractfilename(Opendlg.FileName);

     if FileExists(opendlg.filename) then
    begin
     AssignFile(myfile, opendlg.filename);

    end;
    // Reopen the file in read only mode
   FileMode := fmOpenRead;
   Reset(myFile);

   // Display the file contents
   while not Eof(myFile) do
   begin
     Read(myFile, customer);

   Name.text:=customer.Name;
   LastName.Text:=customer.LastName; 
   //[...] <-- much more fields
end;
end;
end;
```

I do not know if the method is the more accurate but it is what i'm using =(. So how can I make by clicking on the save button I just update the file that was previously saved without the need to reopen the save dialog?  Thanks!

Comment: The crucial part to look at is this: `save.filename`. Once the dialog has been shown, all you are actually taking from it is a file *name*. That's just a string, so can be assigned to a variable for later use. Alternatively, you could simply keep the `myFile` variable "open", and write to it as many times as you want.

Comment: Provide two distinct buttons for 'save' and 'save as'. Don't show the save dialog and use 'opendlg.filename' when save is clicked. Unless 'opendlg.filename' is empty, in that case call the click handler for 'save as' button.

Comment: Typically I would hold the variable called MyFileName: string somewhere and just use the variable value and save to that file name.

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with? Obviously, you need to display the dialog box if the file hasn't already been saved. It's *your* program, and it's *your* saving code, so what's preventing you from knowing whether the file's already been saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ToolButton3Click(Sender: TObject);   
begin    
  if SaveDialog1.FileName = '' then
  begin
    if not SaveDialog1.Execute then
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  AssignFile(myFile, SaveDialog1.FileName);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: This will work but does so at the expense of tying together the UI and the save logic. Any well designed program will have a method for saving that receives the file name as a parameter. Making the save method look up the file name by accessing a file dialog is asking for trouble.